# Can PywinAuto + Robot Framework be used to automate Windows GUI apps and command line emulator based apps

Tags: robotframework, pywinauto, terminal-emulator

I am new to pywinAuto and Robot framework. I want to know if Robot framework along with PywinAuto can be used to automate the windows GUI based applications and also commandline emulator based applications ?

I really appreciate if i get some quick reference guides on this .

Comment: It's worth reading the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html). Robot Framework can be very easily use pywinauto in your steps implementation. But terminal emulators is usually not a target for pywinauto. We have low priority plans to handle console emulators (it's technically possible), but it's not for this year at least.

Comment: I'm not aware about emulators. Didn't surf in this direction. Asking for recommendation is off-topic on StackOverflow. I'd suggest to ask it on [Software Recommendations, tag "automation"](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automation).

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can use the PyWinAuto in Robot Framework is by writing your own libraries with your desired action and importing in Robot Framework.

Below is the information about how the library structure for importing in Robot
[Creating Custom Lib](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries)

When you do that the Function Name will be your Keyword in Robot Framework.

Comment: Thanks for the response , I will check that out